# NULLS being excluded when filtering string literal

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have the below query where I am intending to filter/exclude `WHERE` either the range type or the market concept equals the string literal 'PLACEHOLDER'.  We have found due to feedback that we are actually also excluding any instance where those fields are `NULL`.  This was some surprise to me, any advice on how to explain?

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.MATERIAL, 
       A.MARKET_CONCEPT, 
       A.RANGE_TYPE
FROM VW_MRP_ALLOCATION_COMBINED M
JOIN VW_ARTICLE_ATTRIBUTES_COMBINED A ON M.Material = A.Article AND M.SALES_ORGANIZATION = A.SALES_ORGANIZATION
WHERE M.stock_type = '' 
AND A.market_concept <> 'PLACEHOLDER'
AND A.RANGE_TYPE <> 'PLACEHOLDER' 
AND A.Article in ('BK0348',
'BQ2718',
'BQ2719',
'BS3674',
'CF3607',
'CF3608',
'CF3609',
'CF3610',
'CV5091',
'D94751',
'DH6911',
'DT5039')
AND M.Sales_Organization = 6040;
```

Comment: NULLs are the absence of value, they are not empty strings.  If you want to include a null value you could use  {somevalue} IS NULL

Comment: By definition `null` is an unknown value and is therefore cannot be equal or not equal. If you want to include null values you need to specifically include them e.g. `(A.market_concept <> 'PLACEHOLDER' OR A.market_concept is null)`

Comment: this is ringing some bells.  What would happen if i changed the condition to 'LIKE' instead of a straight forward equals or not equals? That still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Same deal.... you can do `coalesce(A.market_concept,'') <> 'PLACEHOLDER'` but it won't perform as well as the solution I gave above because you're using a function on the value before comparing it,.

Comment: The same thing applies, `NULL <any-comparison-operator> <any-value>` is always `FALSE`

Answer (score 2):

NULL records are drawn using the "IS NULL" keyword for comparison. Here is an example how you can get null records

```
with data
  as (select 'PLACEHOLDER' as market_concept,'PLACEHOLDER' as range_type
      union all
      select 'MarketConcept1' as market_concept,'Rangetype1' as range_type
      union all
      select null as market_concept, null as range_type
      )
 select *
 from data
 where ((market_concept <> 'PLACEHOLDER'
         and range_type <>'PLACEHOLDER'
         )
      --This OR condition brings out the records which are null
      OR(market_concept is null
         and range_type is null
         )
       )

+----------------+------------+
| market_concept | range_type |
+----------------+------------+
| MarketConcept1 | Rangetype1 |
| null           | null       |
+----------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thats assuming both columns are required to be null together though? What if only one is null?

Comment: i have assumed based on the query op shared. a single Null on either fields would be (market_concept is null
         OR range_type is null)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest being explicit:

```
(A.market_concept <> 'PLACEHOLDER' OR A.market_concept IS NULL) AND
(A.RANGE_TYPE <> 'PLACEHOLDER' A.range_type IS NULL) AND
```

Note:  This assumes that `'PLACEHOLDER'` is not `NULL`.  If that is possible, I would suggest asking a new question, with clear sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ISNULL function to consider NULL value same as placeholder.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT M.MATERIAL, 
       A.MARKET_CONCEPT, 
       A.RANGE_TYPE
FROM VW_MRP_ALLOCATION_COMBINED M
JOIN VW_ARTICLE_ATTRIBUTES_COMBINED A ON M.Material = A.Article AND M.SALES_ORGANIZATION = A.SALES_ORGANIZATION
WHERE M.stock_type = '' 
AND ISNULL(A.market_concept,'PLACEHOLDER') <> 'PLACEHOLDER'
AND ISNULL(A.RANGE_TYPE,'PLACEHOLDER') <> 'PLACEHOLDER' 
AND A.Article in ('BK0348',
'BQ2718',
'BQ2719',
'BS3674',
'CF3607',
'CF3608',
'CF3609',
'CF3610',
'CV5091',
'D94751',
'DH6911',
'DT5039')
AND M.Sales_Organization = 6040;
```